# Submit button with no name

Tags: forms, post, curl

```
<input type="submit" value= "OK" />
```

What I normally do is `curl --data "button_name=OK" URL`, but the button here has no name. How can I submit via cURL in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Selectors:**

Without seeing more HTML you could try a CSS selector of `input[value='OK']`,

This says, element with `input` tag having attribute `value` with value of `'OK'`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

The [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) is applied via the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of document.

```
.document.querySelector("input[value='OK']").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that a button doesn't specify a `name` you will not need to send the button's value in the request, `value` just exists to provide the button's label in this instance.

I am not very familiar with curl, but give `curl --data "" URL` a try.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, without name

```
<div class="desc"></div>
<div align="center" class="buttons"><input type="submit"
    value="Login" /></div>
```

In VBA, you can use say

```
dim i as integer
for i = 0 to 19

  if webbrowser1.document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).getAttribute("type") = "submit" then

if webbrowser1.document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).getAttribute("value") = "Login" then
      webbrowser1.document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).click

Exit For

   end if

  end if

next
```

Just Use 19 as an upper bound of the number of input element in the web page and increment it if needed. Once you found which one is it, you can use it straight away